# My C# project that includes some open source GNU General Public License v2 pieces

Tags: licensing

If I include opencvdotnet http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/ in my project, does that mean that my project has to be open source too?  I want it to be closed source.

Comment: IANAL, but generally, yes. GPL licenses (except for LGPL) are viral. Meaning if you use something that is GPL'ed, your code must be GPL'ed too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with two important exceptions:

1. If you use a library **as a library** (not using the source itself) and it is LGPL, then you do not have to GPL.
2. You are only restricted from releasing the project as closed-source. You can use GPL code in a project that is only used by yourself or the client it is developed for, without having to GPL. It's only software that is distributed that must be GPL'd.

Comment: (1) The 'library' mentioned is not LGPL, it is GPL. (2) Providing the code to your client is distribution, and if they ask for the source code you are obligated to give it to them, as well as to provide a copy of the GPL with your software so that they are aware of their rights.

Comment: Also on (1), the exception only applies if you link to the library *dynamically*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. This is the intent of the GPL licence - to ensure that people cannot make closed source software including code licensed with GPL.

Some explanation [here](http://www.gjt.org/info/philosophy/gplreasons.shtml).

> ...the GPL is really much more about ensuring that you, the author, do not lose your ownership of your code in the process of providing it to others for free.